# How to assign from one to another related class, custom assignment or cast in c++?

Tags: c++, casting, assignment-operator

I have a class templated on a floating point type,

```
template <typename fl_t> class generic {
fl_t a,b;
/// a bunch of getters and setters, etc...
}
```

and instantiate with float and double

```
typedef generic<double> dmatrix;
typedef generic<float>  fmatrix;
```

Later, when I want to assign an fmatrix to a dmatrix, I get

```
error: no viable conversion from 'const generic<float>' to 'generic<double>'
note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: 
no known conversion from 'const fmatrix' (aka 'const generic<float>') 
to 'const generic<double> &' for 1st argument

template <typename fl_t> class generic {
```

I wrote an overloaded assignment:

```
template <typename f> generic<f>& operator= ( const generic& g){
    aSET(g.aGET(); // etc
    return *this;
}
```

This compiles but does not solve the problem. Why? Must I write a cast and with what signature?

EDIT: I accepted an answer but for practical work, it seems a cast will also be often needed. One can see how to do it:

```
template <typename fl_t> class generic {
public:
fl_t a;
  double aGET() const {return double(a);}
  void aSET(double x) { a=fl_t(x);}

  template <typename f> generic& operator=(const generic<f>& g){ // assignment
      aSET( g.aGET() );
      return *this;
  }
    
  template <typename f> operator generic<f>() { // constructor
      generic<f> m;   
      m.aSET( aGET() );
      return m;
  }

};

typedef generic<double> dmatrix;
typedef generic<float> fmatrix;

dmatrix fn(fmatrix m){
    dmatrix d=m; // uses constructor, operator()
    d=m;         // uses assignment, operator=
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `const generic<f>& g` (for the parameter)?

Comment: @Nelfeal
  I suppose no, because I want to assign from one type to another. Would this work? template <typename d, typename f> generic<d>& operator= ( const generic<f>& g)

Comment: Is your `operator=` not a member of `generic<fl_t>`? It probably should be and then you can additionally template it on some other `F`: `template<typename F> generic<fl_t>& operator=(const generic<F>& other)`

Comment: @perivesta The assignment operator cannot be non-member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assignment operator takes the current type as parameter:

```
template <typename fl_t> class generic {
// ...
    template <typename f> generic<f>& operator=(const generic& g)
//                                this is generic<fl_t> ^^^^^^^ 
// ...
};
```

If you want to assign from another type, you need to swap the return type and the parameter type:

```
template <typename f> generic& operator=(const generic<f>& g)
```

The type of the parameter is the type of the variable you want to assign *from*. The return type can be whatever you want, but for an assignment operator it's typically a reference to the type of the variable you want to assign *to* (that's the current class) so that you can do something else directly with the result, for example chain assignments (`a = b = c`).

If you don't want the conversion to be implicit (in other words, if you want the assignment to require a cast), you can mark the operator explicit:

```
template <typename f> explicit generic& operator=(const generic<f>& g)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will accept. Do you care to elaborate if its better to write a cast instead in such situation?

Comment: @Kostas: There's no single answer; it depends on the types. I suppose you want to convert between `generic<A>` and `generic<B>` without cast _if and only if_ you can convert from `A` to `B` without cast.

Comment: @Kostas what do you mean "write a cast"? Do you mean an explicit constructor?

Comment: @Caleth,  yes, eventually I had to do that too. Without it, initialization like dmatrix d=f does not work.

Comment: @Kostas Initialization isn't the same as assignment. You need a constructor for that.